# How to declare a set type of an enum type within a generic class

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe4

I came across some strange behaviour in Delphi XE4.

I can't declare a `set` type within a generic class, where the ordinal type is declared within the same class.

For example:

```
TTest<T> = class(TObject)
type
  TEnumType  = (eOne, eTwo, eThree);
  TEnumTypes = set of TEnumType;
end;
```

The above does not compile. The compiler emits error "*E2001: Ordinal type required*".

A non-generic class like

```
TTest = class(TObject)
type
  TEnumType  = (eOne, eTwo, eThree);
  TEnumTypes = set of TEnumType;
end;
```

does compile.

For the generic class to compile successfully, the ordinal type has to be declared outside the class:

```
TEnumType  = (eOne, eTwo, eThree);
TTest<T> = class(TObject)
type
  TEnumTypes = set of TEnumType;
end;
```

---

1. Is this behaviour considered a bug? If yes, has it been fixed in a later version?
2. Does anyone have another workaround? I wanted to declare the types within the class because they are used exclusively in private parts of this class.

Comment: Works in Seattle fine. Just checked. Most probably it's an issue of the XE4 compiler. We had a lot of issues with generics in times of XE4..

Comment: The questions seems to be offtopic here, it should be addressed to Emc. But answer is quite obvious, the code can be compiled without problems in latest version of Delphi, so 1. it is bug  and it is fixed and 2. you suggested a workaround in your question - define TEnumType outside of the generic class (in implementation section if you want to hide it as private).

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn, 1. "But answer is quite obvious, the code can be compiled without problems in latest version of Delphi" - How is that **obvious** if OP  has XE4? 2. Using implementation section wont work because OP needs private TEnumType fields which are declared in the interface section.

Comment: @kobik Anyone can get free/trial version of latest Delphi compiler. Bugs in compiler should be tested in latest version of the compiler, obviously.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn, To your suggestion if I have a compiler bug in Delphi7 for example, I need to install *all* free/trial later versions of Delphi until I can (hopefully) successfully compile my program, instead of asking on SO or researching on the net? Personally I am not going to do that...

Comment: I find it strange that we all accept that bugs are only fixed in a new version of the compiler and not in an update within the same version...

Comment: FWIW Whenever you put a nested type into a generic type ask yourself: do I want a different type here for every different closed generic type or do they in fact all look the same - as in this case with the enum. IMO only when the nested type is based on one or more type parameters it makes sense. If you just want to make some things private then consider adding a non generic base class as ancestor to the generic class where you can put all non generic related code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the issue tracker it seems to be a regression around XE3/XE4 which got fixed in later versions:

- http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=126675
- http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=112682
- http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=117200

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed a bug that is fixed in later versions. Your code compiles in XE7 for instance. Quite possibly it will compile in XE5 or XE6, but I don't have them immediately to hand to check.